# Why am unable to download free app?

Tags: iphone

[image]

I am unable to download free app from App Store. All app showing same thing. I don't know what they want. Each app showing this **it. Plzz help me out soon

Answer (score 1):

Tap Continue and verify your payment information. There is no way around it. If you do not have a credit card or debit card to add to your account, you won't be able to download any more apps.

Comment: Based on your answer the only way to download a free app is to type in credit/debit card details, which is [completely false](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204034).

Comment: @alljamin I am answering the question as posed by the OP, taking their screenshot into account. When prompted for payment verification, generally either a) your last purchase(s) were not successfully charged to your credit card, or b) you are using an existing Apple ID on a new device for the first time. In either case, you'll be required to confirm a credit/debit card in order to use the App Store, even for free apps. Once that's done, you can then remove the card if that option is available. [None is not always available](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT203905).